# RPi 3B, I get IP addr and can ping www.google.com, but can't surf

Tags: pi-3, wifi, internet

Brand new RPi 3B built with NOOBS Raspbian.

Like the title says, I can ping www.google.com just fine, but chromium won't load it, or any other site.

```
$ netstat -rn
Destination  Gateway     Genmask       Flags MSS  Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0      10.0.0.1    0.0.0.0       UG    0    0      0    wlan0
10.0.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 U     0    0      0    wlan0

$ ip addr

wlan0 inet 10.0.0.34/24
```

no proxy, no firewall, sitting behind a comcast modem/router

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a firewall blocking www traffic, but accepting ICMP (Ping) traffic or do you connect to a public WiFi that needs accepting the WiFi policy?

Comment: Do you have a proxy you need to configure?

Comment: From a terminal, can you try typing: curl -S http://www.google.com and post the result.

Comment: If you haven't curl install, install it with "sudo apt install curl"

Comment: do you really expect "sudo apt install curl" to work if ping -c3 google.com does not?

Comment: check and post your dns resolver setup e.g. /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Orange Pi Win Plus running Raspbian Jessie.

Have you tried to access the Chromium settings? In my case none of the pages (nor online nor settings which should be accessed offline won't load).

Instead i installed Iceweasel (Firefox):

```
sudo apt install iceweasel
```

Chromium won't work but at least I can surf the web.